# Is it possible to remove background color when dragging png image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I am trying to make a chess game in react-js using react-dnd

I am trying to make draggable and droppable png images between different div(which represents the board squares)

I tried to set the opacity of the image background-color to 0 but it doesn't work

The problem is that images take the square background-color when i drag them
Is it possible to remove it from the dragging image ? If not is there another drag and drop library that makes it possible ?

Comment: Welcome, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve how to create a minimal complete example

Answer (score 5):

you can add css style to your draggable element:

```css
transform: translate(0, 0);
```

Comment: This is working, but how?

Answer (score 0):

The key is to have the preview contain just the image of the piece, and not wrap more than that. If you edit your question to point to more code, I might be able to help you more.

For example:

```
const Knight = ({ connectDragSource, connectDragPreview, isDragging }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <DragPreviewImage connect={connectDragPreview} src={knightImage} />
      <div
        ref={connectDragSource}
        style={Object.assign({}, knightStyle, {
          opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
        })}
      >
        ♘
      </div>
    </>
    )
   }
```

[Full code. See Knight.jsx](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/gh-pages/examples_js/00-chessboard/final-result?from-embed)